# How to connect to the systemd D-Bus org.freedesktop.timedate1 endpoint in Rust?

Tags: rust, raspbian, dbus

I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero, with the current Raspbian Linux distro. I am trying to write Rust code to set a timezone (like `"America/New_york"`) using the `systemd` D-Bus interface. I found that the `systemd` endpoint for `timedatectl` is `org.freedesktop.timedate1`.

I am trying to use Rust `dbus` crate. I have used `dbus-send` to test first to make sure the method is working:

```
$ dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.timedate1 --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/timedate1 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.freedesktop.timedate1 string:Timezone

method return time=1596003827.891792 sender=:1.47 -> destination=:1.46 serial=3 reply_serial=2
   variant       string "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Using the Rust code:

```
use dbus::blocking::Connection;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let conn = Connection::new_system()?;
    let proxy = conn.with_proxy("org.freedesktop.timedate1", "/org/freedesktop/timedate1", Duration::from_millis(5000));
    // a dbus variant should be returned
    let name = proxy.method_call("org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties", "Get", ("org.freedesktop.timedate1", "Timezone",))?;
    println!("{:#?}", name);
    Ok(())
}
```

I ran it but got an empty result:

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling dbus-test v0.1.0 (/home/pi/dbus-test)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 12.28s
     Running `target/debug/dbus-test`
()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Performing a search for "rust D-Bus" leads to the [dbus crate](https://docs.rs/dbus/0.8.4/dbus/) which has [examples](https://github.com/diwic/dbus-rs#client). The question, as currently formulated, doesn't demonstrate that you've put much effort into solving your problem.

Comment: As I have already said I am new to rust and just trying learn from experts and example. Thanks for your pointer much appreciated.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I have updated my post, any more pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Crate dbus doesn't seem like a good recommendation.

I found the [ruby-dbus](https://github.com/mvidner/ruby-dbus) library easier as it follows the service, object, interface, and method structure of D-Bus. Here is the code I did as a quick test of your above example:

```rb
require "dbus"
sysbus = DBus.system_bus
time_service = sysbus["org.freedesktop.timedate1"]
time_object = time_service["/org/freedesktop/timedate1"]
time_interface = time_object["org.freedesktop.timedate1"]
timezone = time_interface["Timezone"]
puts "Your timezone is set to #{timezone}"
```